# How to reduce disk 100 to min usage while do select request in java derby db

Tags: java, database, derby

I am using Java derby for database. I have 20,00,000 records in my database's table. When I try to fetch the records list or statistics, its take too much time, So I put this section into thread because until record getting fetch, I do not want to get my UI hang. But I Observed that Until all records are get fetched, my system's disk usage reached at 100% and keep constantly 100 for long time until query does finish.

I want that while query fetching the result it's disk usage should not reach till 100% so that I can do some other work and my app UI able to process some other task.

Can I do select query with limit keyword so that I am fetch all records in multiple select queries.

Thanks

Comment: I am using inbuilt HDD of my Laptop. and While I am running select query by program - task manager showing me Active Time  100% and Average Response Time 2739 ms. So my program does not able to do other process and all time is taken by database and my program does wait for response only....

Comment: Do you use an index? Please include your table schema and the query you use.

Comment: I am doing indexing but there type is Varchar and I searched that Indexes are not supported for columns defined on CLOB, BLOB, LONG VARCHAR, and XML data types.

Answer (score 1):

This [guide, Tuning Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tuning/index.html), explains how to tune systems, databases, specific tables and indexes, and queries for performance. This guide also provides an in-depth study of query optimization and performance issues.

You may not use/show all the 20L records same time. Provide pagination in UI and use command like `select * from table1 where ... fetch first 100 rows only`.

Find out where it takes time and CPU usage. If you are using IDE Like netbeans or eclipse, you can do profiling your project and check memory and performance.

Comment: Thanks vels4j and I need to run aggregate method query too on same table ?

Comment: u need to debug your app and query to find where and when it takes time and cpu usage, updated my answer.

Comment: I am running following query 
select status,type,count(*) as total,SUM(filesize) as Totalsize from student group by status,type
I divide this into two section
select status,count(*) as totalcount from student group by status

Comment: I am running following query 
select status,type,count(*) as total,SUM(filesize) as Totalsize from student group by status,type
I divide this into two section
select status,count(*) as totalcount from student group by status
Its taking 7 sec but 
select count(filesize) as sumsize from student group by status
second query taking 514+ second.

Comment: @TejKiran Looks like you need an index on `status`